# Updating live ASP Website (will be overriding existing ASP pages with XHTML pages)

Tags: xhtml, asp-classic

If I'm overriding an active ASP site but will be replacing all existing .asp pages with .xhtml pages, will I have any issues that may arise. Forms have been removed from the site at this time so its virtually static but will be making modifications in the future; ie: video, forms, etc.

At this time all production and testing have been on a demo server and I will taking the site live this weekend.

Comment: No links with database look ups, so do not need to create additional pages to remap links. 

I changed all links *.asp to *.xhtml, did not remap with static handler. Would it be best practice to do the latter by redirecting to a static handler?

Which link-checking tool do you find most useful?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't any problems as long as you did you job right.

How hard that job was depends a lot one the complexity of the old ASP site.

You removed all forms, fine. What about links with database look ups like:

book.asp?isbn=6546465445, how do you handle this using static pages. You would have to create a page for each possible book and remap the links.

Did you change all links from *.asp to *.xhtml or just remapped *.asp to a static handler on the server?

In the past I had to take a very dynamic ASP site and make it work from a CD-Rom without a server.

A good link-checking tool to test the new site is very helpful.

Comment: In the past I had to take a very dynamic ASP site and make it work from a CD-Rom without a server... WTD LOL!

Comment: No links with database look ups, so no need to create additional pages to remap links. I changed all links *.asp to *.xhtml, did not remap with static handler.